# BQ Ubuntu Phone Network not available

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, bq

My BQ Ubuntu phone will not display web pages or access network connections after leaving a secure wireless network, range. I can restart the phone & it works ok.

The fault is that the phone will not switch over to using my carriers data when a wireless network is out of range.

I suspect this is not just an issue with my phone, but an issue with the OS in general.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work if instead of restarting your phone, you enter and exit flight mode?

Comment: I select the airplane mode, then unselect and put the pin again. It's faster than rebooting.

Comment: yes I have found that selecting & unselecting flight mode works... I was not really expecting a magic answer for this king of issue. Though I hope it gets the attention of 'those who update'....
Thanks
James

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug, I experience too. I hope it is this one:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1418077
(as this is reported to be fixed in vivid)

A list of open bugs related to ofono can be found here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ofono/+bugs?orderby=-importance&memo=75&start=0&direction=backwards

Generally for reporting bugs with the phone, a good starting point is here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Avengers

The phone/OS might still be a little rough on the edges, but it is getting better with each update.